Can you win this territory game while going second?
Rules
Alice and Bob take turns claiming territories on a map with a finite number of territories. After their first turn, a player may only claim a territory if it borders one they already own. If a player has no moves available, they lose their turn. Once neither player can move, a player wins if they own more territories.
Examples
On the map below, play might proceed as follows:

Alice claims B,
Bob claims C,
Alice claims A,
Bob claims D,

resulting in a 2-2 draw.

On this map, here's how the game might go:

Alice claims B,
Bob claims C,
Alice claims D,
Bob loses his turn,
Alice claims A,

and Alice wins 3-1.

Question
It's possible for Bob to win on both of the maps shown, but only if Alice makes a mistake; if she plays correctly, she wins or draws as demonstrated.
Is there a map where Bob can guarantee a win?

Is the number of regions finite?

@DL33. I would think so, otherwise the game will never end, so there’s no winning

@Pranay not necessarily, they could agree to have 1 minute of thinking time and cut it in half every round, this way they could cover a countable inifinity of regions in 4 minutes.
The reason I'm asking is that I have a solution for this case

@DL33 Good question! Yes, the map is finite. Playing on an infinite map is an interesting idea, perhaps while posing a different question.


 Yes, e.g.


 
 If Alice chooses green, Bob can choose the opposing red and get 2 green. If Alice chooses red, Bob can choose an adjacent green and get 2 green. Bob can thus score 9 points.


For completeness: If Alice chooses yellow, Bob chooses the nearest green and gets 12 points.

Nice answer! Do you know if there's a map without "holes" where Bob can win? In your map, the region bounded by the red and green regions is a "hole" in the map.

@Pranay make the red and green regions triangles, then they can touch in the center with their vertices (judging from examples in the question, regions only touching with a vertex are not considered connected)

@DL33. Ah yes, makes sense, thanks!

Actually, only one yellow is required at each end.  Then the map can be drawn as a size-3 triangle divided into unit triangles.

Very clever.  I tried that map, but it never occurred to me that Bob could win by (Rot 13) abg cynlvat nqwnprag gb nyvpr ba uvf svefg zbir.
